# 'ResizableBox' cannot be used as a JSX component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, resizable

Does anyone experience this same issue? I can't get trough this error
[Here is a screenshot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsLjH.png)

C:/Users/marcu/OneDrive/Desktop/test/src/components/resizable.tsx
TypeScript error in C:/Users/marcu/OneDrive/Desktop/test/src/components/resizable.tsx(30,11):
'ResizableBox' cannot be used as a JSX component.
Its instance type 'ResizableBox' is not a valid JSX element.
The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("C:/Users/marcu/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode'.
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactPortal': key, children, type, props  TS2786

```
28 |   }
29 |
```

> 30 |   return <ResizableBox {...resizableProps}>{children};
> |           ^
> 31 | };
> 32 |
> 33 | export default Resizable;

I try everything, I even downloaded the project from the resource folder of the course I'm learning from and it has the same issue

Comment: Can you add the code of the ResizableBox component, because the problem is in the JSX that is returned by this component?

Comment: it kind of sounds like there are some formatting issues in your file - in particular it's very weird that it's expecting a string type that's an 'import(...' string. please provide more of the code you are trying to debug, and check that your formatting is legible so we can see what the error message is and what your code is, they look like they're all piled together in your post

Comment: Please post a [minimal, reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and not a screenshot.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Enter a code in terminal
{npm i react-resizable}

And Import {   import { Resizable } from 'react-resizable';   }

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).